# Error type not detected in pyhon in using try...except... method

Tags: python

My code is as follows

```py
#This program can make files of any type as you wish

from os import path

#Ask's For extension
file_extension = input("Please enter the file type as .extension (E. g. ->> .txt , .py , .png , etc): ")

#Takes number of files that are required and if something wrong is entered such as char then throws error
while True:
    try:
        number_of_files = int(input('Please Enter the number of files needed: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a valid character...")

#Takes the name of file
file_name = input("Please enter the name of file: ")

#Takes path of file
# Here is the error
while True:
    try:
        path_name = input("Enter the path if specfied else ignore\n(E.g. ->> D:/alpha/ would store in folder alpha inside Disc D)\nNote add a \"/\" in between and also at end: ")
        break                    
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Enter a valid path or just press enter to continue")

#To make a appropriate name
file_name_with_path = path.join(path_name, file_name)

#Makes appropriate files
for i in range(1, (number_of_files+1)):
    with open(f"{file_name_with_path}-{i}{file_extension}", "w") as f:
        f.write('')
```

Here At second try... except ... there is some problem
And want to resolve it
Note :- Dont want to make new file and want to just give user a another chance to enter the path

Comment: Well, your try/except is at another part of the code, not where the error is. It not makes sense to have the try/except there. And please, fix the indentation

Comment: Your code is wrongly indented and this causes errors. You need to fix the indentation of your code

Comment: Calling `input()` to fetch a string is never going to throw a `FileNotFoundError`. You likely want to take the string the user provides (path_name) and pass it to something like `pathlib.Path(path_name).is_dir()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the file error is not the input statement instead its the file open statement that is outside of the try except statement.
We can fix this like so.

```
while True:
    try:
        path_name = input("Enter the path if specfied else ignore\n(E.g. ->> D:/alpha/ would store in folder alpha inside Disc D)\nNote add a \"/\" in between and also at end: ")
        file_name_with_path = path.join(path_name, file_name) 
        for i in range(1, (number_of_files+1)):
            with open(f"{file_name_with_path}-{i}{file_extension}", "w") as f:
                f.write('')     
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Enter a valid path or just press enter to continue")
```